# Upgrading laptop HDD to an SSD

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, ssd, upgrade, sata

I have an Acer Aspire V5-471G Laptop with 466GB Seagate HDD using SATA 2.0(3.0Gb/s) interface. I'm planning to upgrade my HDD with a faster Samsung 840 EVO SSD which uses SATA 3.0(6.0Gb/s) but is also compatible with SATA 2.0.

Since my laptop has only SATA 2.0 interface, I assume that even if I upgrade to the above mentioned SSD, there won't be much difference in performance as the SATA 2.0 interface will not be able to fully utilize the full speed advantage of the speed of SSD which is 400+MB/s.

Will I be able to notice the difference even if I go ahead the upgrade to SSD with my existing SATA2 interface?

Will there be noticeable difference in battery life?

Answer (score 0):

You won't get full speed but you will notice a significant improvement in all aspects of your laptop, and I also found far less heat as well.